# How to use the primary key at insert

Tags: mysql, insert, primary-key

I have a table with an auto incremental primary ID, and I sometimes need to insert rows in this table, which have a column that needs to be the same value as the primary ID. How can i set this column to be the same value as the primary ID before the row is inserted? Is this even possible, or would I have to do another update query after the row has been inserted?

Comment: Why would you want a column have same value as primary ID. If you have to, you need another update query.

Comment: So you want to store the primary key of a row in a row twice ?

Comment: I can smell bad design from here. We'll need to understand more of your actual use-case (and why this is actually not as horrible as it looks like currently) before anyone is willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of referencing a new key is to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. You could try inserting `LAST_INSERT_ID()` as the value:

```
INSERT INTO FOO (dependent_field) values (LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

> You can retrieve the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function. These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts.

Caveat: I have not tested this, so it's quite possible that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will not evaluate properly within the same statement as the insert that generates the new ID. If that's the case, the only solution I can think of is to do an update afterwards, as you suggest.